# Read PHP echo into string in Android

Tags: android

I need to read this echo:

http://wee.co.il/Ski/weatherScript.php?op=3

into string, I have tried:

```
class RetreiveEcho extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    private static final String TAG = "Her";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://wee.co.il/Ski/weatherScript.php?op=3");

        Log.d(TAG, "Hello!");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d(TAG, ""+response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

For now I only see in my log:

```
 org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@4132e5a8
```

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973454/cannot-get-httpresponse-content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HTTPResponse object in your code is a java object holding the response. It isn't a plain string. Therefore, printing the object results in the given log output. To access the php echo, you could try following code:

```
response = httpClient.execute(targetHost, targetGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String htmlResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Comment: What is targetHost and targetGet?

Comment: It is just a different way to execute a request with the httpClient class I am using in my code. With targetHost I am passing following object to the execute method: `HttpHost targetHost = new HttpHost("host.com");` With targetGet I am passing following object: `HttpGet targetGet = new HttpGet("/this/that.html");`

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the `HTTPEntity` from the `HTTPResponse` using its [`getEntity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpResponse.html#getEntity%28%29) method. You can write its content to an output stream by [`writeTo(OutputStream outstream)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#writeTo%28java.io.OutputStream%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply fetch by doing this

```
   HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient(); 
   HttpPost httppost=new  HttpPost("http://192.168.10.104/android/sample.php");
   HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   String str =  EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```